# git merge and rebase errors in workflow

Tags: git, version-control, merge, rebase

Firstly, this is not a question on how rebase and merge compares!
The TL;DR is: how do other large teams deal with same-file merges.

I've experience some issues(code getting messed up and people having concerns) when i use git MERGE

In a larger team, it frequently happens that 3 or more people work on the same files - during the same day (configuration files, so we don't split them).

### My normal approach:

- Create a new branch from master called cool_branch
- work on some cool code in the new branch and commit
- merge from master, and then merge back to master

### Here are the git commands

```
git checkout master
git checkout -b cool_branch
* do stuff *
git merge master
* double-check merge issues and everything builds *
git checkout master
git pull
git merge cool_branch
git push
```

... then others REBASE or MERGE their work someone in the middle, or afterwards.

Most of the people wants everyone to change to REBASE, and say MERGE is evil and merge causes the problems.

I really prefer a single merge, but it has caused some screwed up final results in master.

BTW: its not a million changes, but say 20, and some people refactor a bit and I would like to get a consistent workflow for everyone.

**THUS...**

1. how do you guys/gals on large teams deal with same-file merges?
2. If some people use the merge technique, and others use rebase would it totally mess with the repository. I.e., do merge and rebase play well together?
3. What is easiest to "undo" ?

Thanks.

Comment: We always use `fetch` then `rebase` as opposed to `pull`. I don't see why you're using `cool_branch`. Also, please edit your question and use git commands in a code block to show your normal approach as it's currently quite hard to read

Comment: Your workflow appears to be perfectly valid for merging.  I am unsure what your question is.  Are you asking about how to convince the rebase people why merging is better?

Comment: Thanks Tim.  Yes, I am trying to figure out if I should change to rebase, or if we keep our seperate ways would totally mess with the repository.  I.e., do merge and rebase play well together?